# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current'). When trying to import the react three fiber canvas

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I keep getting the error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current').
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBqCu.png)

When attempting to import the React Three Fiber canvas into my live WordPress website as a plugin, I can't seem to find any solutions to fix it. Any suggestions?

index.jsx

```js
import App from "./App";
import {
    render
} from '@wordpress/element';

/**
 * Import the stylesheet for the plugin.
 */
import './style/main.scss';

// Render the App component into the DOM
render(< App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';

function App() {

    return (
        <Canvas>
            <color attach="background" args={['skyblue']} />
        </Canvas>
    )
}

export default App;
```

package.json dependencies

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^26.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.80.9",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.7",
    "@types/three": "^0.155.1",
    "three": "^0.156.0"
  }
```

I've already tried it with some different components that I have, and I didn't encounter any errors when importing one of them. So the problem seems to be in the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to set width of canvas component.

```
<div
   className="container"
   style={{
     display: "flex",
     justifyContent: "center",
     alignItems: "center",
     height: "100vh",
    }}
 >
   <Canvas style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", position: "relative" }}>
   </Canvas>
</div>
```